# Hooking the readfile function doesn't show all read operations of a process

Tags: io, window

On the Windows system, I tried to intercept all read operation of specific process.

To do that, I hooked the function `readfile` in `kernel32.dll`. It seems to work nicely on most programs which do a read operation. But when I tried to hook the process `itunes.exe` while playing some MP3 files, it cannot intercept any of read operations.

When I check it with the 'Process Monitor', it displays the `readfile` operation periodically. Is there any other way to access file without using `readfile` function in `kernel32.dll`?

Why can't the injected DLL intercept itunes' read operations?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are several ways to read a file:

- `ReadFile` in Kernel32
- `ReadFileEx` in Kernel32
- `CreateFileMapping`/`MapViewOfFile` in Kernel32, which lets you read a file by mapping it to memory and reading the memory instead; it is **very likely** that this mechanism is being used.
- `NtReadFile` in NTDLL (called by `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx`, not normally used directly)